# Resources for datasets

Tags: dataset

Is there a go to source for searching for data sources? Like a way to ask google, specifically to show data files?

Specifically, I'm looking for data on the number of smart phones and tablets sold in countries around the world.

Any ideas where I can look?

Comment: https://www.forbes.com/sites/bernardmarr/2016/02/12/big-data-35-brilliant-and-free-data-sources-for-2016/#512c8a29b54d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browse the following sources to see if you could find them:

- [UCI ML Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php)
- [OpenML webpage](http://openml.org/) (login required to download)
- List of datasets for ML research ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_datasets_for_machine_learning_research))

Hope this helps.